# Resource Designer Files - Change Template

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, stylecop, resource-files

When changing a localized resource file, such as resources.de.resx the designer code gets regenerated blank.

**How can I change this to be the auto generated code message?**

I.e.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The lack of the auto-generated code message is causing it to be picked up by Code Analysis / Source Analysis and putting it back after every edit is starting to become irratating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a StyleCop.Settings file to the project and uncheck the analyise designer files and StyleCop will ignore the resource.de.designer.cs file.